# MouseDown event for NSButton?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, ibaction, nsbutton

I'm trying to call an ibaction method when an NSButton is clicked down, but I can't figure out how to get do to that instead of having it called when clicked up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[yourButton sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[btn setAction:@selector(Method:)];

[btn setTarget:objectThatRespondsToMethod];
```

Comment: use this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html